# How do I secure this code? jQuery and Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I m building a little multiple choice app. The below two options are generated from a query. After one of them is pressed, ajax sends data to a table, the "next" button is inserted and when pressed two more options are available.

I just noticed that if an element with the `id="4"` and `class="pick"` is copied and inserted in the html through the inspect element option, id 4 can be voted over and over ... 
wwhat's a good way to prevent this?

```
<ul class="thisClass">
    <li class="first"><a href="#" class="pick" id="4">mercedes</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#" class="pick" id="8">alfa romeo</a></li>          

</ul>
```

The jQuery

```
$('.thisClass').on('click', '.pick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    var pickID = $(this).attr('id');
    var notPickID = $('.pick').not('#' + pickID).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://mywebsite.com/index.php/home/user_pick",
         data: {pick : pickID, notPick : notPickID},
         success:
              function(data){

                $("ul.thisClass").html(data.content);

                $("div#next_button").html('<a href="#" class="next" id="next">Next</a>');

              }
          });
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send back to the server all the info needed to ensure there are no duplicates.

1. The `userID`
2. The `surveyID`
3. The `questionID`
4. The `answerID`

When you get the values on the server items 1, 2, & 3 must be a unique combination... otherwise the user is trying to submit multiple answers (intentional or otherwise).

*Note: That if your questions are **not** tied to a survey consider #2 above as optional when determining uniqueness.*

In addition... once you've registered the user's answer to a given question you *could* have your AJAX return a flag that tells you that your JavaScript code should disable that question or display it in a "done" state so that the user doesn't try to re-answer it.

Comment: Ok ... let me explain this a bit. What I m trying to do won't have questions. The user only gets the two choices, then two other choices. They are randomly picked from a table. So there are no right answers or wrong answers. I might have been a little misleading when I said multiple choice .. sorry about that.

Comment: @ciprian that's fine but the only way you can stop someone from submitting duplicate results is if you know on the server if the submission coming in is a unique response.  If in your case there is no "survey" (e.g. a set grouping of questions) then your uniqueness check would be based on the (`userID` + 'questionID`)

Comment: so I would need to generate an id for the question? but I have no question. Just two options generated randomly. User picks one, than moves on to two more, and so on.

Comment: Correct - you will need to track that a user has already answered a "question". e.g. say the choices are "Coffee" or "Tea"? In order to record my vote (and make sure I don't vote more than once you will need to register my vote as {userID:"scunliffe", questionID:123, vote:"Coffee"}.  When you see another vote come in with my userID and the same questionID you know that it is invalid because you already have a vote for that combination.  However you must have a questionID or you won't know if I can vote on the next poll "Coke" or "Pepsi"? {userID:"scunliffe", questionID:456, vote:"Coke"}

Answer (score 0):

In fact, they don't need to *copied and inserted in the html through the inspect element option* to "*hack*" your website, just send a POST request with data `{pick : pickID, notPick : notPickID}` to `http://mywebsite.com/index.php/home/user_pick` and your website is down. You must do the validation at **server side**.

A good approach to solve this problem is to prevent multiple pick **from the same user** (or same IP address if your picking system do not require an account), get the `UserID` or `UserIP` in your controller to check if the user is picked or not.

Comment: It does require an account, I will enable the Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) in Codeigniter and I validate everything in the controller using the form validation library. See my reply to scunliffe ... it's not a normal multiple choice test or quiz. Users will just get two random choices from a table and will need to pick one. I just noticed a little exploit in my code and wanted to see how to fix it.

Comment: If you do not require an account you will not be able to enforce uniqueness and you **will** be subject to "Ballot Stuffing" issues etc. e.g. I own/have access to at least 15 Internet connected devices... many with multiple browsers installed.  If you are not verifying accounts I **could** vote 10,20,30... times on any question if I was so determined.

Comment: @ciprian I think scunliffe have answered your question. You just need an unique key (`userID` + `questionID`) in your database and that's all.